# Punctuation within a question

Tags: punctuation, commas

How do you punctuate "Are you Mr. Jones?" Is that correct or should it be "Are you, Mr. Jones?"

Comment: Please add more context. They are both correct, depending on the context.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the intended meaning. "Are you Mr Jones?" means you are asking whether he is named Mr. Jones.  "Are you, Mr. Jones?" requires context to make sense, e.g.:

> I am a member of the committee.  Are you, Mr. Jones?

In this example, you already understand that the man is Mr. Jones, and you are asking him whether he is a member of the committee.  In essence, the latter sentence is merely short for:

> Are you a member of the committee, Mr. Jones?

Naturally, if the context is different, the meaning of *Are you, Mr. Jones?* also changes.